# MS Excel: Count the number of cells in a column that have the same number as the cell to the left of it

Tags: excel

How can I do to count the number of cells in a column, that have the same text as the cell to the left of it?

Seems it should be pretty simple but I can't find a way or any answer online. Thank you.

> =COUNTIF(P$2:P$125,"="&$O2)

```
=COUNTIF(P$2:P$125,"="&$O2)
```

This is almost perfect except the formula tries to match always with cell value of O2. Which is great for P2, but when I get to P99 for example, I want to see if it is exactly the same as O99, and similarly then equal.

Comment: You already have it right.  When you copy that formula down, Excel will adjust the relative references (those without the `$` 's).

Comment: That's not how mine works...
I have a 'C' in O2 and it tries to match every cell in column P with that O2 (i.e. checks only against the 'C')

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT and limit the ranges to the extents of the data while maintaining the same size of range for both columns.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(O$2:O$125=P$2:P$125))
'dynamic range
=SUMPRODUCT(--(O$2:index(O:O, match("zzz", O:O))=P$2:index(P:P, match("zzz", O:O))))
```

The `--` (or *double unary*) coverts the TRUE/FALSE results to ones and zeroes.

Comment: Do I just copy-and-paste the entire 3rd line?
It's not working for me...
What's the "zzz" for?

Comment: The *zzz* finds the last row containing text in column O and uses that as the terminating row for both column O and column P. You stated that there was text in the columns. If there were numbers or dates, then change *zzz* to *1e99*. Yes, it is a copy and paste, turn-key solution. It is expected that there are no error codes in either column.

Comment: I'm putting this text in cell P126. (to display the sum of all the numbers in column P)

Comment: Or rather, not the sum. But the number of cells above my cell that have the same text/numerical value as the cell to its left of it.

Comment: If your range(s) are static then just use the first formula. The second was intended for situations where the number of text values changes.

Comment: I don't know why, it still doesn't seem to be functions at it should. Trying =SUMIF(P2:P125,COUNTIF(P2,"="&$O2),$Y2:$Y125) and that gives only 0. What's wrong with this?